# CSS Sprites horrible slow using Edge or Internet Explorer 11

Tags: svg, less, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, css-sprites

We have a Singe Page Application using AngularJS 1.5 and it works smoothly using Chrome but unfortunately we also support IE 11+ and probably Edge and using these browsers, the performance is close to horrible (more than two seconds delay). It seems that it has something to do with the way we are using css sprites because if I remove the background-image property everything works smoothly again. My experience on css is not very high thus I hope that somebody with a deeper insight has a hint about performance optimizations. The sprite svg file (325KB 2350px x 2340px) looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 2350 2340" enable-background="new 0 0 2350 2340" xml:space="preserve">
     <symbol  id="ic_x5F_website_x5F_blk" viewBox="0 -50 50 50">
     ...
     <use xlink:href="#ic_x5F_website_x5F_blk"  width="50" height="50" id="XMLID_496_" x="0" y="-50" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 284.9999 155)" overflow="visible"/>
     ...
</svg>
```

And the relevant css/ less styles are

```
.ico() {
    &:extend(.ic-mixin);
}

.ic {
    .ic-mixin;
}

.ic-mixin {
    background-image: url('../icons/spritesheet.svg');
    background-size: @spritesheet-width @spritesheet-height;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.icon(@column, @row, @color: blk, @offset: 0px, @offsetY: @offset) {
    .createIcon(@column, @row, @color, @offset, @offsetY);
}

.createIcon(@column, @row, @color, @offsetX: 0, @offsetY: @offsetX) {
    @positionX: @initIconGapX + @iconColumnWidth * (@column - 1);
    @positionY: @initIconGapY + @iconOuterSize * (@row - 1);

    & when (@color = wht) {
        background-position: -(@positionX + @iconOuterSize + @offsetX) -(@positionY + @offsetY);
    }

    & when (@color = blu) {
        background-position: -(@positionX + @iconOuterSize * 2 + @offsetX) -(@positionY + @offsetY);
    }
}

.icon-virtual {
    &:after {
        .ico();
        .icon(4, 23, wht, 15px);
        content: ' ';
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: @green;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        right: 2px;
    }
}
```

Why is Chrome so much faster? Is this a cache problem? Is IE trying to fetch the huge file over and over again? Could there be a problem with the svg file itself? Or is the css to complicated? Are we missing some important properties? Is IE too slow finding the correct background position?

Thanks a lot for any hint!

**UPDATE**
Exchanging the big file with a different much smaller svg does not help in improving the performance.

Comment: can you post a reproduction? hard to help without seeing a live site

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your comment. Currently the site is not live yet. :) But one little update: We are now using icon fonts for all icons and performance is much, much better now.